# Entity Framework not cascade deleting

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, devart

In short EF default is to delete cascade. I have a parent/child relationship I set up using Entity Developer by Devart. It is set to delete cascade. The parent table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Tools` (
`ToolNumber`    TEXT,
`ToolID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
);
```

The child table has the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `FirstParts` (
`FirstPartID`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`DateTime`  TEXT,
`ToolID`    INT32 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `FK_FirstParts_Tools` FOREIGN KEY(`ToolID`) REFERENCES 
`Tools`(`ToolID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I can add records to the parent/child by using the following code. When I use this I DO get a record in each table and the ToolID is set correctly.

```
using (var context = new Entities())
{
    var query = from t in context.Tools
                        where t.ToolNumber == "Hello"
                        select t;

    if (!query.Any())
    {
          var tool = new Tool()
                     {
                        ToolNumber = "Hello",
                        FirstParts = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<FirstPart>() { new FirstPart() { DateTime = "Same text" } }
                   };

        context.AddToTools(tool);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When I use the following to delete the parent the child is left hanging:

```
 using (var context = new Entities())
 {
     var query = (from t in context.Tools
                         select t).FirstOrDefault();

     if (query != null)
     {
        context.Tools.DeleteObject(query);
        context.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

If I use SQLite Browser and do the following SQL then both parent and child gets deleted properly So I know it is not SQLite.

```
DELETE FROM Tools WHERE Tools.ToolID = 6;
```

I have looked for the following to make sure Cascade delete is not getting overridden:

```
OnModelCreating(false)
```

It is not present in the code created by Entity Developer.

What could be causing EF to not cascade delete?

Comment: `When I use the following to delete the parent the child is left hanging:`- What does `child is left hanging` means here? Is it deleting only parent keeping child intact? Explain the scenario properly of what when you delete parent.

Comment: could you show us some code around your model binding?

Comment: @TanvilArjel - The parent is being deleted leaving the children in the table without a parent.

Comment: @noobed - I'd be happy to. The code is autogenerated by Entity Developer and is about 500 lines.How to post that much code?

Comment: @noobed - here is a pastbin. https://pastebin.com/q080bYrs

Comment: @EricSnyder as I can see there should be an option like this in your Entity Developer: `Model Explorer > ModelName.Store > Constraints > open Storage Constraint Editor for your constraint and set the "Delete Action" property to Cascade`

Comment: @noobed - It ios. Please see image. https://imgur.com/a/uWCEvWi

Answer (score 0):

Please add "Foreign Key Constraints=On;" to your connection string to fix the issue. Refer to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/?Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection~ConnectionString.html.

Comment: Thank you. I have found connection strings in three different places. 1) DataModel.edps under <Connection /> 2) In DataModel1.Designer.cs in public Entities() 3) In app.config. My model was not set to use app config so I deleted that connection string. I added "Foreign Key Constraints=On;" to both connection strings and it was ignored. When I delete the last child from the child table the record in the parent table is still not deleted.